# Order item custom options

Tags: custom-options, database

In which table I can see ordered item's custom options and its chosen value.

I can see a `product_options` column in table `sales_flat_order_item`, but not sure is it same as product's or item's custom option?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can access them in `sales_flat_order_item`, in the column you originally believed them to be in.

The data in `product_options` is serialized, so if you unserialize it you end up with something like:

```
array(6) {
  ["info_buyRequest"]=>
  array(5) {
    ["uenc"]=>
    string(56) "aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS90ZXN0LWNhdGVnb3J5L3Rlc3QuaHRtbA,,"
    ["product"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["related_product"]=>
    string(0) ""
    ["options"]=>
    array(2) {
      [2]=>
      string(1) "2"
      [1]=>
      array(1) {
        [0]=>
        string(1) "1"
      }
    }
    ["qty"]=>
    string(1) "1"
  }
  ["options"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(7) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(25) "Custom Option for Product"
      ["value"]=>
      string(16) "Custom Option 1 "
      ["print_value"]=>
      string(16) "Custom Option 1 "
      ["option_id"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["option_type"]=>
      string(9) "drop_down"
      ["option_value"]=>
      string(1) "2"
      ["custom_view"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
    [1]=>
    array(7) {
      ["label"]=>
      string(27) "Custom Option for Product 2"
      ["value"]=>
      string(15) "Custom Option 3"
      ["print_value"]=>
      string(15) "Custom Option 3"
      ["option_id"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["option_type"]=>
      string(8) "checkbox"
      ["option_value"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["custom_view"]=>
      bool(false)
    }
  }
  ["giftcard_lifetime"]=>
  NULL
  ["giftcard_is_redeemable"]=>
  int(0)
  ["giftcard_email_template"]=>
  NULL
  ["giftcard_type"]=>
  NULL
}
```

As you can see, if you grabbed `options` from that array, you would be able to loop through the options on the product, including their ID's.

You can get the information for a specific option a few ways, direct SQL is the least advisable, however it does give you an idea of how the options are stored within Magento.

Direct SQL to pull options and most of their information:

```
SELECT
    _cpo.product_id,
    _cpo.type,
    _cpo.is_require,
    _cpo.sku AS catalog_product_option_sku,
    _cpo.file_extension,
    _cpo.image_size_x,
    _cpo.image_size_y,
    _cpo.sort_order AS catalog_product_option_sort_order,
    _cpop.price,
    _cpop.price_type,
    _cpot.title,
    _cpotp.price,
    _cpotp.price_type,
    _cpott.title,
    _cpotv.sku
FROM catalog_product_option _cpo
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_price _cpop ON (_cpop.option_id = _cpo.option_id )
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_title _cpot ON (_cpot.option_id = _cpo.option_id )
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_type_value _cpotv ON (_cpotv.option_id = _cpo.option_id )
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_type_price _cpotp ON (_cpotp.option_type_id = _cpotv.option_type_id )
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_type_title _cpott ON (_cpott.option_type_id = _cpotv.option_type_id )
WHERE _cpo.option_id = **OPTION_ID**
```

The above should give you an idea of the structure of the options in Magento.

I would suggest getting these options within Magento though, which can be accomplished by doing something similar to:

```
$order = Mage::getModel('sales/order')->load(**ORDER_ID**);
$items = $order->getAllVisibleItems();
foreach ($items as $item):
    $options = $item->getProductOptions();
    foreach ($options as $option):
            //$option contains the option information for item
    endforeach;
endforeach;
```

$option will contain something similar to:

```
array(5) {
  ["uenc"]=>
  string(56) "aHR0cDovLzEyNy4wLjAuMS90ZXN0LWNhdGVnb3J5L3Rlc3QuaHRtbA,,"
  ["product"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["related_product"]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["options"]=>
  array(2) {
    [2]=>
    string(1) "2"
    [1]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "1"
    }
  }
  ["qty"]=>
  string(1) "1"
}
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  array(7) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(25) "Custom Option for Product"
    ["value"]=>
    string(16) "Custom Option 1 "
    ["print_value"]=>
    string(16) "Custom Option 1 "
    ["option_id"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["option_type"]=>
    string(9) "drop_down"
    ["option_value"]=>
    string(1) "2"
    ["custom_view"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
  [1]=>
  array(7) {
    ["label"]=>
    string(27) "Custom Option for Product 2"
    ["value"]=>
    string(15) "Custom Option 3"
    ["print_value"]=>
    string(15) "Custom Option 3"
    ["option_id"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["option_type"]=>
    string(8) "checkbox"
    ["option_value"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["custom_view"]=>
    bool(false)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to get the options table for a specific product id:

```
SELECT
    _cpo.product_id,
    _cpo.option_id,
    _cpo.type,
    _cpo.is_require,
    _cpop.price,
    _cpop.price_type,
    _cpot.title,
    _cpotv.sku,
    _cpotp.price,
    _cpott.title AS Description
FROM catalog_product_option _cpo
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_price _cpop ON (_cpop.option_id = _cpo.option_id )
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_title _cpot ON (_cpot.option_id = _cpo.option_id )
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_type_value _cpotv ON (_cpotv.option_id = _cpo.option_id )
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_type_price _cpotp ON (_cpotp.option_type_id = _cpotv.option_type_id )
LEFT JOIN catalog_product_option_type_title _cpott ON (_cpott.option_type_id = _cpotv.option_type_id )

WHERE product_id = 99999;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see the custom option values in `sales_flat_quote_item_option` table. But reference id will be `quote_id`. From your `sales_flat_order_item` you can see `quote_item_id` field.